# Writing a regexp as argument to gsub! method -- stumped?

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4, gsub

In my Rails 4.2.6 / Ruby 2.2.4 app, I have a db query method that generates a string; for example:

```
"Chest - pectoralis, Quads - quadriceps, Hamstrings - biceps femoris"
```

However, the result I want is:

```
"Chest, Quads, Hamstrings"
```

The domain tracks 21 muscle groups, which means the generated string can have a lot of different combinations. However, the string will always have the same pattern, that is: "common muscle name - technical muscle name".

With conditional logic, I can get the result I want by passing "string" arguments to the gsub method, like this:

```
 if @muscle_group_ids == [1, 13, 14]
    @muscle_group_names = MuscleGroup.where(id: @muscle_group_ids).map { |n|   n[:name]
   }.join(', ').gsub!("Chest - pectoralis", "Chest").gsub!("Quads -    quadriceps", "Quads").gsub!("Hamstrings - biceps femoris", "Hamstrings")
end
=> "Chest, Quads, Hamstrings"
```

That approach isn't viable; it's tedious and brittle. There must be a better way to remove dashes and technical names from the generated strings. I'm stumped on how to best accomplish this.  Is it possible to write a regexp to achieve the desired result, and how?  Is there an easier, better, cleaner approach to achieve what I'm trying to do? Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, don't do `MuscleGroup.where(...).map {|n| n[:name] }` in Rails if you can do this instead: `MuscleGroup.where(...).pluck(:name)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
irb(main):001:0> s="Chest - pectoralis, Quads - quadriceps, Hamstrings - biceps femoris"
irb(main):002:0> s.gsub(/(\w+)\s+-\s+[^,]*/, '\1')
=> "Chest, Quads, Hamstrings"
```

That searches for any number (`+`) of "word" characters (`\w)`, which it remembers because they're in parentheses, followed by space (`\s+`), a hyphen, more space, and anything that's not a comma (`[^,]*`). It replaces all of that with just the word characters that it remembered (`\1`).

The pattern is pretty specific and would need to be modified if, for example, the common name might be more than one word.

Also, I just did `gsub` above to return (and display, in `irb`) the result; to modify the string in place you would use `gsub!`.

Comment: Thanks.  These are all good answers. I awarded points to other answers.

Comment: @codeinspired: If anything, lassvi should get the accepted answer. He was the first one to notice that you're treating the problem backwards, and proposed a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 5):

You could just split the name on `" -"` in your map function, and only return the first part like this:

```
if @muscle_group_ids == [1, 13, 14]
    @muscle_group_names = MuscleGroup.where(id: @muscle_group_ids).map { |n|   
        n = n[:name].split(" -")[0] 
    }.join(', ')
end
=> "Chest, Quads, Hamstrings"
```

Answer (score 2):

## MuscleGroup#common_name

The easiest way would be to define a new method inside `MuscleGroup` model :

```
def common_name
  name.split(' - ').first
end
```

Your code becomes :

```
@muscle_group_names = MuscleGroup.where(id: @muscle_group_ids).map { |muscle_group|
  muscle_group.common_name }.join(', ')
```

## Double split

If for some reason, you already have a complete string, a double split might be more robust and easier to read than a big regexp.

You can split around `', '` to get an array of `"common muscle name - technical muscle name"`. You can then split each one of those strings around `' - '` and keep the first part :

```
"Chest - pectoralis, Quads - quadriceps, Hamstrings - biceps femoris".
  split(', ').map{|s| s.split(' - ').first}
# ["Chest", "Quads", "Hamstrings"]
```

Once you have the array, you can join back to a string :

```
"Chest - pectoralis, Quads - quadriceps, Hamstrings - biceps femoris".
  split(', ').map{|s| s.split(' - ').first}.join(', ')
#  "Chest, Quads, Hamstrings"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 r = /[[:alpha:]]+     # match one or more letters
      [\s+[:alpha:]+]* # match one or more spaces followed by one or more letters,
                       # zero or more times, to match any words after the first
      (?=\s+-\s+)      # match a hyphen surrounded by whitespace in a positive lookahead
     /x                # free-spacing regex definition mode

"Chest - pectoralis, Quads - quadriceps, Achilles heel - Achilles tendon".scan(r)
  #=> ["Chest", "Quads", "Achilles heel"]
```

Comment: What if the common name has two words?